Can I prevent shadows to overlay other views?
I have views with shadows with a big shadow blur. I want the shadow to go behind the other views. Tried some stuff with zIndexing, but nothing seems to work. This is what is happening:

Simplified code:
import SwiftUI

struct TestBackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.white.frame(height: 80)
                .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)            

            Color.white.frame(height: 80)
                .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestBackgroundView()
}

In my own code, the views are buttons, where the button have a background shadow, that also changes based on the pressed state.
I've tried to overlay 2 VStacks in a ZStack, where de background is only on the bottom vstack. But then I cannot have a clear color to place the shadow on, so my animation of the button looks off, as the background of the first VStack is still visible.

struct TestBackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Color.white.frame(height: 80)
                    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)

                Color.white.frame(height: 80) // Color.clear will not show shadow
                    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)
            }
            VStack {
                Color.white.frame(height: 80)

                Color.black.opacity(0.8) // Simulating pressed state
                    .padding()
                    .frame(height: 80)

            }
        }
    }
}

Any other solutions possible?

By default, a shadow will only cover views that came earlier in the layout. Views that follow in the layout will cover the shadow of an earlier view. So the problem only exists for the shadow of the second view in the VStack.
If you know the spacing of the VStack then you could use a .mask to stop the shadow from going over the preceding view:

apply the mask with alignment: .top

use negative padding to allow the mask to extend into the space between the views

apply a generous height to the mask, to give enough space for the shadow below the view.


VStack(spacing: 10) {
    Color.white
        .frame(height: 80)
        .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)

    Color.white
        .frame(height: 80)
        .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)
        .mask(alignment: .top) {
            Rectangle()
                .padding(.top, -10) // VStack spacing
                .frame(height: 200, alignment: .top)
        }
}


If you didn't know the height of the view concerned then you could use a GeometryReader to measure it:
// (second case)
Color.white
    .frame(height: 80)
    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)
    .mask(alignment: .top) {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Rectangle()
                .padding(.top, -10) // VStack spacing
                .frame(height: proxy.size.height + 100, alignment: .top)
        }
    }


This is much cleaner. No need to keep state. I like it.

Ok, kept on going, found a solution, will enter it here for others to find.
My final solution was to create a ZStack with a background layer for the shadows. And let the buttons propagate their pressed state to the ZStack so the pressed state can also be handled by the background layer.
Normal state:

Pressed state:

Code:
import SwiftUI

struct TestBackgroundView: View {

    @State private var pressedButton: Int?
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Color.white.frame(height: 80)
                    .padding(.horizontal, pressedButton == 1 ? 24 : 0)
                    .animation(.spring(response: 0.2, dampingFraction: 0.6), value: pressedButton == 1)

                    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)

                Color.white.frame(height: 80)
                    .padding(.horizontal, pressedButton == 2 ? 24 : 0)
                    .animation(.spring(response: 0.2, dampingFraction: 0.6), value: pressedButton == 2)

                    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 40)
            }

            VStack {
                Button { } label: {
                    Text("1").frame(height: 80)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .buttonStyle(TestButtonStyle(isPressed: { isPressed in
                    if isPressed {
                        pressedButton = 1
                    } else {
                        if pressedButton == 1 {
                            pressedButton = nil
                        }
                    }
                }))                

                Button { } label: {
                    Text("2").frame(height: 80)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .buttonStyle(TestButtonStyle(isPressed: { isPressed in
                    if isPressed {
                        pressedButton = 2
                    } else {
                        if pressedButton == 2 {
                            pressedButton = nil
                        }
                    }
                }))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let isPressed: (Bool) -> Void

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(.white)
            .padding(.horizontal, configuration.isPressed ? 24: 0)
            .animation(.spring(response: 0.2, dampingFraction: 0.6), value: configuration.isPressed)

            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed) {
                isPressed($0)
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestBackgroundView()
}


